# Attributed text in MDCTextField not working

Tags: ios, swift

i have dates in format e.g. "Today 28. 3. 2019" and i am trying to set the color of the first word ("Today") to gray but the code does not work and the color does not change. Changing non-attributed text color works fine. Do you have any ideas where might be a problem ?

Thanks

Edit: We use MaterialComponents pod for TextFields

```
func setStartDate(_ date: String?) {
        if let date = date {
            let firstWord = date.components(separatedBy: " ").first
            let firstWordRange = (date as NSString).range(of: firstWord!)
            let attributedDate = NSMutableAttributedString(string: date)

            attributedDate.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor,
                                        value: UIColor.gray,
                                        range: firstWordRange)

            startDateBox.input.attributedText = attributedDate
        }
    startDateBox.input.text = date
    }
```

Comment: Check your if part, you are assign simple text again.

Comment: Yes, that part was incorrect, but still not working.

Comment: Check whether you set 'startDateBox' text somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Remove your simple text assignment `startDateBox.input.text = date`

Rest is good

```
 func setStartDate(_ date: String?) {
            if let date = date {
                let firstWord = date.components(separatedBy: " ").first
                let firstWordRange = (date as NSString).range(of: firstWord!)
                let attributedDate = NSMutableAttributedString(string: date)

                attributedDate.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor,
                                            value: UIColor.gray,
                                            range: firstWordRange)

                startDateBox.input.attributedText = attributedDate
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot to mention that we use MaterialComponents pod, so there might be an issue